# OpenCV Python: Detect If point is within Bounds of Object

Tags: python, opencv, bounds, object-detection

I am working with Python and OpenCV to detect objects and execute actions. I have an image(made by removing all colors except outline color) that is the outline of my object. 
Currently, I am creating a contour with that image and detecting if the center of the image is within a certain distance of the centroid of the contour. 
This works for some cases but is not very reliable.

```
M = cv2.moments(lrgst_cnt)
cx = int(M['m10']/(M['m00']+0.000000000000001))
cy = int(M['m01']/(M['m00']+0.000000000000001))
if 110 <= cx <= 150 and 40 <= cy <= 210:
    print "do action"
```

I'd like to know if there is a more reliable way to detect if my point is within the outline of the object.

Comment: If your boundary can be written as a polygon, [`cv2.pointPolygonTest`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=pointpolygontest#cv2.pointPolygonTest) could be useful.

Comment: Thanks man. This should help a lot. Now I need to work on making my contour be the entire outline instead of part of the outline.